# Has the 20 synonym max on entities been removed?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Last week I was getting an error when trying to save an entity containing more than 20 synonyms. Does anyone know if this limit was removed and if so, what is the limit now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soon! It is a limitation in the simulator, we are actively working on a fix.  Stay tuned.